# Problems using the kf-function in the KFAS package

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate a local level state space model on the data Nile from the default R library.

```
install.packages("KFAS")
library("KFAS")


#Example of local level model
#Using the Nile observations
data(Nile)

yt<-t(data.matrix(Nile))
s2_eps<-15099
s2_eta<-1469.1

f.out<-kf(yt = yt,  Zt = 1,  Tt=1,  Rt=1,  Ht= s2_eps,  Qt=s2_eta,  a1 =
            0,  P1=1e7)
```

When I evaluate the function, I get an error saying that the function kf does not exist. However, the kf-function should be a part of the KFAS package.

Hope someone is able to help.

Thanks

Comment: According to the [reference manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KFAS/KFAS.pdf), there is no `kf` function in package `KFAS`. Why do you think it should be part of this package?

Comment: I am going through the example in section 2.3, where it said it should be contained in the KFAS package:   http://www.jstatsoft.org/v41/i04/paper

Comment: It's a paper from 2011. There was probably some changes in the package in between. According to [this page](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/KFAS/docs/kf), `kf` function was present in version 0.6.1, but not after. The current version is 1.1.1.